# URL Blocked on Facebook

Tags: facebook, url, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook won’t share a link to my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185406/facebook-wont-share-a-link-to-my-site)

When I post my URL on Facebook I get an error stating: "The content you're trying to share includes a link that's been blocked for being spammy or unsafe."

The domain used to be parked from the previous owner and had a URL redirect so that is likely why Facebook blocked this URL to begin with. However, now I am developing the domain and need to include social plugins from Facebook but can't.

I've tried the "Help Centre" and "Let us know" link a thousand and one times but never get a reply. Is there a way to inform Facebook this domain is now safe and to get them to unblock it?

Changing the domain is a last resort as I've already made my investment in it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *The domain is www.funnyfails.com

Comment: See point 2 in the referenced question.