# facebook scraper stops reading my meta data

Tags: facebook, debugging, object, scraper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook won’t share a link to my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185406/facebook-wont-share-a-link-to-my-site)

I have 2 websites that fail to show an image when pasted into facebook. So I went to the facebook object debugger and compare what the scraper sees to what view source sees.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fvspwebandvideo.com%2F

Both of my failing pages dies on the line:

Because it gives no error, it just stops reading at that point, I am clueless as to what to try.

Any ideas? I wondered if the title tag having html entities would have an effect.

paxtonsgrill.com fails as well, but allaroundloveland.com works. All 3 are wordpress sites, but I am a PHP developer so if I can figure out what is wrong, I can most likely fix it.

Thanks

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpaxtonsgrill.com is the other failing debug link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your site's Charset.

If you click on `See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL` link on their page, You should notice their scraper breaks at `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss왩">` (After rss its actually a + on your site) and checking your site's source code, I see you have `utf-7` charset.

So i did a quick test and i can confirm its the character encoding issue. Just change it to `utf-8` and everything should be working fine.

Also if you check your `allaroundloveland.com` site's source code, you can see it has the right charset but whereas your other sites have wrong charset (Idk if you added that yourself for some reason? but their scrapers are breaking with that charset).

Hope this helps and let me know if its working for you.