# Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api

Go to:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

We enter for example these and it works fine:
http://www.toppform.se/ShowBlog/Vgen-ur-tstrningen
http://www.toppform.se/ShowBlog/Jennys

But this does not:
http://www.toppform.se/ShowBlog/Nervergiveupjess

We get:

```
Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.
```

Comment: Have you got the solution for this?

Comment: No, sadly i never got any answer, what i did was a check to see if it was Facebook that was requesting and sent a more plain version of the content to them. Ugly workaround but worked.

Comment: Very fast reply. Thanks

Comment: I agree, now i actually configured notifications i hope

Comment: try the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185406/facebook-wont-share-a-link-to-my-site