# Facebook URL Linter gives "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped"

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api, scrape

I don't used to post any questions on forums but this time, I have no other solution...

The Facebook URL Linter gives me the following "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped" on this URL: http://phrasesbox.com/test.html

But with this URL is OK: http://jeudephrases.com/test.html

My problem is that these 2 domains are located on the same server, and the "test.html" file is unique (these 2 domains point to the same folder).

This gives me a very big problem because there is no preview on sharing contents on Facebook... (title, description, image).

All was working fine until one month ago. It's like if my phrasesbox domain were in a blacklist but when I share contents, there is no SPAM notice.

Same problem with 2 other domains that also point to the same folder.

Any idea??

/* EDIT */
I have already lost 70% of visits ...

Comment: try the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185406/facebook-wont-share-a-link-to-my-site